# How to send request with request payload instead of form data? (iphone)

Tags: iphone, cookies, request, nsurlrequest, payload

Usually when I look at the POST requests that are send to a webpage by my browser, they often include Form Data. I then make my own NSURLRequest appending httpbody with similar paramaters, and thus send POST requests to the page I need. However I recently encountered with a situation where a POST request doesn't havve a Form Data at all, but Request Payload instead. I have no idea what it means. Should I send the request appending httpbody with the paramaters from request payload? So far it hasn't been working for me though.

Here how this request payload looks:

```
------WebKitFormBoundarySomeLettersHere
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipient"

theRecipient
------WebKitFormBoundarySomeLettersHere
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="recipients"

theRecipients
------WebKitFormBoundarySomeLettersHere
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="inReplyToPimId"

thePimid
------WebKitFormBoundarySomeLettersHere
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

theMessage
------WebKitFormBoundarySomeLettersHere--
```

Among the request headers I found interesting:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySomeLettersHere
Cookie:JSESSIONID=someId; PPLoggedIn=myId; pimConversation=true
```

I checked among the cookies I have, that "pimConversation" is missing. Maybe it is the problem? But again I made such cookie and add it to cookies storage.

What do you think I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance!